# Is the value of `null` allowed for fields that are required?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-schema

In MongoDB, what does it mean to have the `required = true` condition for a field in a collection?

Can the value be `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`required = true` seems to be using Mongoose, so it doesn't accepts null values.

> By default, a value satisfies the required validator if val != null (that is, if the value is not null nor undefined).

Can be found in their docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required

MongoDB has a similar approach, but you declare all fields in the `required` option

i.e.:

```
...
required: [ "name", "year", "major", "address" ]
...
```

More can be found [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/schema-validation/)

Answer (score 0):

No value cannot be `null`, `required: true` will throw an error if `null` value is passed to the field on which `required` is implemented.

As per Mongoose [documentation on required](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required)

> By default, a value satisfies the required validator if `val != null` (that is, if the value is not null nor undefined)

Keep in mind, that's the default behavior, so there is a possibility for custom implementation.